# How to Pass empty C# parameter to VBA method expecting a ParamArray argument

Tags: c#, vba, reflection, com, com-interop

I have a COM application object that has a VBA method signature like:

```
Function DoSomething(ActivityName As String, ParamArray ActivityParams() As Variant)
```

I'm trying to call the function from my C# code, but I'm unsure how to pass values to the 2nd argument *ActivityParams()*. I *should* be able to pass *no* ActivityParams, or one, or many, so I'm guessing an array at the C# end will be required.

For now, I don't need to pass any ActivityParams values at all, for the second argument, but I probably will need to soon enough.

Is this sufficient to call the DoSomething method, if I don't have any values to pass to ActivityParams?

```
public override void DoSomething(MyActivity myActivity)
    {
        Application.DoSomething(myActivity.ToString(), null);
    }
```

And, how would I vary it to be flexible enough to pass 0, 1 or more values?

Comment: [Object for missing (or optional) arguments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306683)
 ```object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;```.